# Learning C by Tokenizing a String without strtok

Tags: c, strtok

I am learning `C` by looking at assignments from Standford and other Universities (I am not a Student anywhere).

One of those assignments is to implement a simpler `strtok`, however I am having trouble getting it right.  Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int tokenize(const char **input, const char *delimmter, char buf[], int buf_size)
{
    int i = strcspn(*input, delimmter);
    strncpy(buf, *input, i > buf_size ? buf_size : i);
    *input += i+1;

    if (i == strlen(*input))
        return 0;

    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const char *input = "super-duper-awesome-magnificent";
    char buf[11];
    while (tokenize(&input, "-", buf, sizeof(buf)))
    {
        printf("Next Token : %s\n", buf);
    }

    return 0;
}

Next Token : super
Next Token : duper
Next Token : awesome
Next Token : magnificent
Next Token : Next Token
```

If I understand pointers and the memory (stack/heap) correctly, then among the things wrong with my implementation are:

> 1) It's incorrect: It prints all the tokens followed by the phrase
>   "Next Token" because that's the next piece of memory in the program. 
>   It only stops because there's nothing left on the stack
>
> 2) I am not really using buf_size correctly.  Any token longer than 11
>   characters will cause problems.

But my aim now is just to fix the first problem, which is how to terminate the while loop.

Comment: May I suggest that you solve this yourself without help.  You are not far.  The exercise will teach you more than just getting the right answer and moving on to the next problem.

Comment: That's a great point! Can you offer a hint?

Comment: @SamHammamy try by moving while loop inside `tokenize` function and return pointer instead const.

Comment: I think I need to do some reading on `gdb` and see how I can use it to solve this.  Trial and error is just not doing it

Comment: Yes.  Trace through the execution with gdb and see what happens that you don't expect or like.  Use printf debugging as well to display the values of variables during execution.

Comment: `strtok(3)` has this prototype: `char *strtok(char *src, char *delim);` and not the one you used.  It returns `NULL` to say there are no more tokens in the string and uses `NULL` as `src` to find the second and next tokens.  If you don't begin with that, there's little thing to say about.

Comment: the loop in main should be something like: `for(p = my_strtok(input, "-"); p; p = my_strtok(NULL, "-"))` to cope with `strtok(3)` interface.  This should be a hint for your problem.

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do this:

```
int i = strcspn(*input, delimmter);
```

`i` will have the length of the segment which consists entirely of bytes not in
`delimmter`. If a charatcer in `delimmter` is in `*input`, `i` will be shorter
than `strlen(*input)`.

```
strncpy(buf, *input, i > buf_size ? buf_size : i);
```

This line copies at most `i > buf_size ? buf_size : i` characters in `buf`,
let's say `i` is larger than `buf_size`, that means you will copy `buf_size`
elements in `buf`, but it won't be '`\0`'-terminated, because `strncpy` does not
write the `'\0'`-termination if non is found. So **you** have to set the
`'\0'`terminating byte.

```
strncpy(buf, *input, i > buf_size ? buf_size : i);
buf[(i >= buf_size ? buf_size - 1: i)] = 0;
```

If `i` is smaller than `buf_size`, then the position `i` is where the
`'\0'`-terminating byte should go. If `i` is larger or than `buf_size` or equal,
then `buf_size-1` is the last position in the buffer and that's where the
`'\0'`-terminating byte should go.

This

```
*input += i+1;
```

is not correct for all cases. If no delimiter is found in `*input`, then `i`
will be the same as `strlen(*input)`. In that case you want that `input` points
to the `'\0'`-terminating byte and not past it, because you would be accessing
memory out of bounds in the next iteration. If `i` is smaller than the length,
then the increment is fine. So, the correct version would be

```
*input += i + (i != strlen(*input));
```

This

```
if (i == strlen(*input))
    return 0;
```

should be removed. When this is the case, the whole `*input` strings must be
returned and the function should return 1. That's why you can remove it. But
what you have to test is whether `*input` is an empty string. In that case, all
tokens have been returned and you should return 0. Do this check prioir to the
`strcspn` call.

So

```
int tokenize(const char **input, const char *delimmter, char buf[], int buf_size)
{
    if(**input == 0)
        return 0;

    int i = strcspn(*input, delimmter);
    strncpy(buf, *input, i > buf_size ? buf_size : i);
    buf[(i > buf_size ? buf_size - 1: i)] = 0;

    *input += i + (i != strlen(*input));

    return 1;
}
```

This would give you the result you want. If you change in the `main` function
the declaration of `buff` to `char buf[3]`, this would be the output:

```
Next Token : su
Next Token : du
Next Token : aw
Next Token : ma
```

which would be correct.

Comment: One again you do me a great service Pablo! Thanks again!  I need to re-read your answer a few times in the morning to fully understand.  I was just reading about how `\0` is always causing problems :) I tried to do that `**input == 0` check differently but didn't get it right.  Glad to learn that's how it's done!